# How to upload an asset from a front-end form

Tags: assets, frontend

I've found information on [how to upload an asset as part of creating an entry](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms). What I am trying to do is upload an asset from the frontend *without* creating an entry. I have a logged in user, and what I would like them to be able to do is upload an asset to a folder that is unique to that user (folder name = username). Help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not going to be possible to do without a plugin.

The plugin would need to provide its own [Controller](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/controllers) which does the following:

1. Grab info about the uploaded file using [UploadedFile::getInstanceByName()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/etc/web/UploadedFile#getInstanceByName-detail)
2. Determine the ID of the asset *folder* you want to upload the file to using [AssetsService::findFolder()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#findFolder-detail)
3. Move the file into the folder using [AssetsService::insertFileByLocalPath()](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/AssetsService#insertFileByLocalPath-detail)

Here’s an example:

```php
// Get info about the uploaded file
$file = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('fileInputName');
$tempFilePath = $file->getTempName();

// Find the target folder
$folder = craft()->assets->findFolder(array(
    'sourceId' => 1,
    'path'     => 'subfolder/path/'
));

// Turn the file into a managed asset within that folder
craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath(
    $tempFilePath,
    $file->getName(),
    $folder->id,
    AssetConflictResolution::KeepBoth);
```