# How do I upload an asset in Craft 3, via PHP

Tags: assets, php, craft3

I've found various answers on how to upload assets via PHP for Craft 2, however nothing for Craft 3.

All answers use the method:

```
craft()->assets->insertFileByLocalPath()
```

E.g: [How to upload an asset from a front-end form](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5104/how-to-upload-an-asset-from-a-front-end-form)

I was wondering what the equivalent is for Craft 3.

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I finally figured out how to upload an asset, however I still don't understand why the `insertFileByLocalPath` has been removed.

```
/**
 * @param UploadedFile $uploadedFile
 * @param int $folderId
 * @return Asset
 * @throws BadRequestHttpException
 * @throws UploadFailedException
 */
protected static function uploadNewAsset(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folderId) {


    if (empty($folderId)) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('No target destination provided for uploading');
    }

    if ($uploadedFile === null) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('No file was uploaded');
    }

    $assets = Craft::$app->getAssets();

    if ($uploadedFile->getHasError()) {
        throw new UploadFailedException($uploadedFile->error);
    }

    // Move the uploaded file to the temp folder
    if (($tempPath = $uploadedFile->saveAsTempFile()) === false) {
        throw new UploadFailedException(UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE);
    }

    if (empty($folderId)) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('The target destination provided for uploading is not valid');
    }

    $folder = $assets->findFolder(['id' => $folderId]);

    if (!$folder) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException('The target folder provided for uploading is not valid');
    }

    // Check the permissions to upload in the resolved folder.
    $filename = Assets::prepareAssetName($uploadedFile->name);

    $asset = new Asset();
    $asset->tempFilePath = $tempPath;
    $asset->filename = $filename;
    $asset->newFolderId = $folder->id;
    $asset->volumeId = $folder->volumeId;
    $asset->avoidFilenameConflicts = true;
    $asset->setScenario(Asset::SCENARIO_CREATE);

    $result = Craft::$app->getElements()->saveElement($asset);

    return $asset;
}
```

and then in my controller I can simply use

```
$service->uploadImage(UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('photo'), 1);
```

Comment: insertFileByLocalPath() was a casualty of a lot of element save refactoring. Basically in Craft 3, we want all element saves to go through craft\services\Elements::saveElement().

Comment: Fair enough, any plans to add helper methods like above to make it easier for people to use? The code above isn't the most intuitive.

Comment: I don't think so, as it only helps a pretty narrow use case. What if someone wants to set content on the asset? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Not an actual answer to your question, but more of a pointer in the general direction.

Docs for Craft 3 can be found [on Github](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/), they are a work in progress by the looks of things.

In particular you'll probably want to look at the [Plugin Development - Services](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/services.md) section.

Now together with the above docs, and a fresh install of Craft 3 itself, you should be able to find what you are looking for in the `Assets` Service. Which you'll find in the following location of you install:

`craft/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Assets.php`

The `saveAsset` method looks like it might be a good candidate for what you are doing.

Hopefully that should help a little bit.

Just so you know, I'm not being deliberately vague. I'm only just starting to look into Craft 3 and was having a browse around the source code myself and it looked like it might help :)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. I'll update my question when I get home, I've since figured out how to save an uploaded asset, and I've written a helper method for it. It seems very complicated though, so I'm still wondering where the previous helper method from Craft 2 disappeared to.

Comment: I've added an answer with my code for uploading a new asset. (Did it as a new answer since code in comments doesn't work)